# Does the Lead.archnum variable of an RPM Header serve any purpose?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I am working on some changes to the [Redline rpm package](https://github.com/craigwblake/redline) and a question has come up about specifying architectures.  The architecture is specified as a string within the rpm filename, e.g. `xyz-1.2.3-noarch.rpm` or `xyz.1.2.3-i386.rpm`, in which the former would be appropriate for packages with no binary components for example, java packages, python packages, script file collections, etc., and the latter would be appropriate for packages containing native code libraries for intel 386 processors.

That's all pretty clear.

However, there is also an internal value in the header of the rpm file called the `Lead` and this section contains a short member called `archnum`.  This is described [here](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/pkgformat.html):  where we see the following structure described

```
struct rpmlead {
    unsigned char magic[4];
    unsigned char major, minor;
    short type;
    short archnum;
    char name[66];
    short osnum;
    short signature_type;
    char reserved[16];
} ;
```

What values should be placed in `archnum` are not described here.

You can find an [old and somewhat cryptic reference to this subject here](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/ch-rpm-file-format.html).
After listing the architectures that were in use at the time the document was written it goes on to say:

> This list will almost certainly change. For the most up-to-date list,
>   please refer to the file /usr/lib/rpmrc. It contains information used
>   internally by RPM, including a list of architectures and equivalent
>   code numbers.

That comment is out of date in that the rpmrc file is found on more modern systems at `/usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc`and here we do find a number of architectures defined and some code numbers, and compatibility indications, etc.

This is all very vague.  Nowhere is there an authoritative list of which architectures should use which code numbers and the reference to getting the "most up-to-date list" from a file on your own system seems rather quaint.

This brings up the question: what, if anything, does the rpm installer do with these archnums?  Googling

> archnum rpm

I find a number of hits that take me pages showing source code mentioning archnum.

This would include http://rpm.org/api/4.4.2.2/rpmlead_8c-source.html in which the methods readLead() and writeLead() are visible, with code to read and write these values.  There are many other links to other versions of this source file, all of which have similar code.  There are also links to rpmParse.c and to header files defining the structure above.

**What I do not find in this search, is any code that checks this value and does anything based on it.**

And so my question.  is `Lead.archnum` a value with any significance today, or is it a vestigial trace of some earlier conception of how these packages would be processed, without any current significance?

This matters to me because I want any changes in the Redline-RPM package to be correct. and it's not entirely clear how serious an issue this is in actuality.  **I suspect that lead.archnum is no longer significant, and I'm hoping that someone reading this would be able to confirm that.**

**Update:** another clue that archnum may no longer be significant is is this bit of the rpmrc file (from an rpm v.4.8.0 installation) :

```
#############################################################
# Canonical arch names and numbers

arch_canon:     athlon: athlon  1
arch_canon:     geode:  geode   1
arch_canon:     pentium4:       pentium4        1
arch_canon:     pentium3:       pentium3        1
arch_canon:     i686:   i686    1
arch_canon:     i586:   i586    1
arch_canon:     i486:   i486    1
arch_canon:     i386:   i386    1
arch_canon:     x86_64: x86_64  1
arch_canon:     amd64:  amd64   1
arch_canon:     ia32e:  ia32e   1
arch_canon:     em64t:  em64t   1
```

The x86_64 architecture uses the same code number as the i386 in spite of the fact that they are certainly not the same!

Comment: Lead.archnum could be used by repositories to find packages matching your architecture. This might be an idea for further investigation. If Lead.archnum is not used how will the architecture by determined? From the name? I use this to build RPMs: https://ctron.github.io/rpm-builder/rpm-mojo.html. It allows to specify the architecture as string.

Comment: I suspect that yes, by the name, is how the search you describe might be accomplished.  Certainly, it would be more efficient to do it based on a list of file names, rather than by having a read a bunch of files.  Had not been aware of the ctron package you reference.  Thanks.  But I am using Gradle and the gradle-os-package plugin uses Redline, so it's not an option.  Redline's user interface also specifies Strings (or actually enum values) to specify the architecture.

Answer (score 3):

The rpm lead is/was an "abandoned data structure" in 1997 (see "Maximum RPM" appendix.

The arch in the lead is not used for any purpose for most of this century.

Comment: Thanks very much, Jeff, for confirming my suspicion.  Can you also confirm that for any user of rpms requiring to know what architecture an rpm was built for, the answer is to look at the appropriate section of the filename?  Of course, the filename could be a "lie", but so, with a bit more difficulty, could be the archnum short inside the file.

Comment: Also, what is the most recent version of Maximum RPM?  The one at the top of Google is Copyright 2000: http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/

Comment: The best answer for detecting arch (or os) is to query for RPMTAG_ARCH or RPMTAG_OS which are string valued and extensible (unlike the arch enum in the lead which breaks every time there is a new architecture, and/or arch alias).

Comment: Even better that RPMTAG_{ARCH,OS}, is RPMTAG_PLATFORM, which contains the usual CPU-VENDOR-OS-GNU hyphenated tuple.

Comment: "Maximum RPM" was converted from TeX to DocBook in 2003 (or so) and can be found on the internet. Because copyrighted by RedHat, the book can not be published nor released by non-RedHat without permission.